# Trying to replicate .bind() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and I am trying to replicate some of the built-in methods like .push() .indexOf() etc..

So far so good and it is helping me a lot to learn the core of JavaScript.

But I came across .bind() and I can´t figure out a way of knowing the function that is calling the .bind() and tell my new .bind2() method to use it with the new THIS from our Object.

This is what I am trying:

```
const human = {
  firstName:"Humano",
  lastName: "Doe",
  fullName: function() {
    return this.firstName + "  " + this.lastName;
  }
};

const member = {
  firstName:"Member",
  lastName: "Nilsen",
};

Function.prototype.bind2 = function(obj) {
        if (typeof obj !== "object" ) {throw `${obj} is not an Object, I will work hard to return undefined later on`};
        return function(){
                return obj;
        }
    };

let testBind2 = human.fullName.bind2(member);
console.log(testBind2()); // {firstName: 'Member', lastName: 'Nilsen'}
```

So all I could do is to return the THIS from the Object passed as an argument but I have no idea how I can grab inside the .bind2() the fullName method (or any method that we want to bind)  from the object that is actually calling the method .bind2().

Once we could grab the fullName we can pass it to bind2() and tell it to use THIS from our object.

This is only for the sake of learning and it would be amazing if someone could tell me if it is possible and how.

Thank you

Comment: hint: `var that=this;`  and `return that.apply(this, arguments)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**don't modify `window`**

`bind` is part of `Function.prototype`, so you can try implementing it there. Here is a possible polyfill -

```js
Function.prototype.bind2 = function bind2(context, ...a) {
  return (...b) => this.call(context, ...a, ...b)
}

const human = {
  firstName:"Humano",
  lastName: "Doe",
  fullName: function() {
    return this.firstName + "  " + this.lastName;
  }
};

const func = human.fullName.bind2(human)

console.log(func())
```

```
Humano Doe
```

**binding arguments**

`bind` can receive arguments when calling `bind` and also when the bound function is called. Below we demonstrated that `myfunc.bind2` has the exact same behavior as `myfunc.bind` -

```js
Function.prototype.bind2 = function bind2(context, ...a) {
  return (...b) => this.call(context, ...a, ...b)
}

function myfunc(a,b,c) {
  console.log("name", this.name)
  console.log("sum", a + b + c)
}

const human = { name: "julio" }

const hello1 = myfunc.bind(human, 10)
const hello2 = myfunc.bind2(human, 10)

hello1(20, 30)
hello2(20, 30)
```

```
name julio
sum 60
name julio
sum 60
```

**not just for objects**

Do not make the assumption that `bind` only works with objects. You can bind any variable to the context -

```js
Function.prototype.bind2 = function bind2(context, ...a) {
  return (...b) => this.call(context, ...a, ...b)
}

function myfunc(times) {
  return this.toUpperCase().repeat(times)
}

const foo = myfunc.bind2("hello")

console.log(foo(10))
```

```
HELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLO
```

**without `call`**

In your comment you asked how to write `bind` without using `Function.prototype.call`. If you want to include context in your binding, the only other option is to use `Function.prototype.apply` -

```js
Function.prototype.bind2 = function bind2(context, ...a) {
  return (...b) => this.apply(context, a.concat(b))
}

function myfunc(times) {
  return this.toUpperCase().repeat(times)
}

const foo = myfunc.bind2("hello")

console.log(foo(10))
```

**without context**

`.call` and `.apply` give you the ability to set the `this` context for the bound function. You can instead add a `context` parameter. Choose any name for it that suits you -

```js
Function.prototype.bind2 = function bind2(...a) {
  return (...b) => this(...a, ...b)
}

function myfunc(context, times) {
  return context.toUpperCase().repeat(times)
}

const foo = myfunc.bind2("hello")

console.log(foo(10))
```

**any other way?**

Is `.call` and `.apply` the *only* way to set the context? For all intents and purposes, yes. However, you can write a very bad hack if you just want to see how something like this could be possible. One caveat of this approach is that it only works for object contexts, not simple primitives like number or string -

```js
// ⚠️ demo only, never do this
Function.prototype.bind2 = function bind2(context, ...a) {
  if (typeof context != "object") {
    throw Error("context must be an object")
  }
  return (...b) => {
    const bound = Symbol()
    context[bound] = this
    const value = context[bound](...a, ...b)
    delete context[bound]
    return value
  }
}

function myfunc(a,b,c) {
  console.log("name", this.name)
  console.log("sum", a + b + c)
}

const hello = myfunc.bind2({ name: "julio" }, 10)

hello(20, 30)
```

```
name julio
sum 60
```

Comment: Thank you very much !!

That was very clear and helpful. 

Just to keep on digging deeper... how would you do it withouth using .call() ?

Thanks again !!

Comment: @Julio I added two more sections to address this comment. Please let me know if that helps :D

Comment: That is great thank you.

So for what I can see, if we don´t use .apply or .call we cannot create a bind method that takes the context and set the "this" for the bound function, right?

Therefore, if we don´t modify the function we want to pass, in your example "myfunc" in order to pass the context there, it would be impossible to create the bind ?

I have been trying something like this without using call or apply:

Function.prototype.bind2 = function bind2(contex, ...a) {
 funPassed = this;
 return function(...b) {
  this = context;
  funPassed(contex, ...a, ...b);
 }
};

Comment: But it gives an error saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

I guess we cannot declare "this" to anything

Comment: that is correct. in order to set `this` you must use `call` or `apply`. you can do it without but it is extremely hacky and you should **never** do it. see the last section in my answer for a demo.

Comment: Amazing Mulan !! Thank you very much

I just wanted to know how bind really works by trying to create a method that does the same thing. 

It is a good way to really dig into the core of JavaScript.

Thank you very much again

Comment: You're very welcome. Just for your reference, the reason the last one works is because if I call `someObj.someFunc(args)`, the context of `someFunc` will automatically be set to `someObj`. So in order to replicate that, we assign the function, `this`, to `context[bound]`, and then call the function `context[bound](...args)` which sets `context` as the context for the function :D

Comment: Amazing, that is exactly what I wanted to learn !! 

A different way to set THIS !!

It is similar to what I was trying but getting the only the "sum" of the myfunc but not the this.name.

Function.prototype.bind3 = function(context, ...a) {
 
 return (...b) => {
  context = this;
  const value = context(...a,...b);
                delete context;
  return value;
 }
};

You said if we call someObj.someFunc(args), the context of someFunc will be set to someObj... but in my example above it doesnt...

Why can I not just declare context = this and then call the function ?

Comment: Sorry I have been looking at Symbol() and I think I understand now...

Does your example work because we are assigning "this", which is a function, to the object as a new property with the KEY as the Symbol just created and then declare its value to the "myfunc" ??

I have created another version and it WORKS !!

Function.prototype.bind3 = function(context, ...a) {
 
 return (...b) => {
  const key = "key";
  context[key] = this;
  console.log(context);
  const value = context[key](...a,...b);
  return value;
 }
};

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct. When an object with a function property is called, the object is set as the `this` context. In your previous example, `context = this; context(...a, ...b)` is no different than `this(...a, ...b)` which is an ordinary function call that does not set `this`. In your `bind3` be careful with `key = "key"` as `context` may already have a `key` property present. `Symbol()`  was used in my example because it is guaranteed to be unique and I made sure to `delete` the key after the function was run :D

Comment: Completely understood !!

Thank you very much Mulan again for your effort and help.

It made me improved a lot and learnt plenty of things.

See you around !!